# NestJS rate limit rate not same as defined

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am trying to set a rate limit of 3 requests for every 60 seconds. However, the throttle limit seems not accurate.

I am following the guides from https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting#rate-limiting and have set a @Throttle() decorator in a API route.

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @UseGuards(ThrottlerGuard)
  @Throttle(3, 60)
  @Post('login')
  @HttpCode(200)
  async login() {
    // login code logic
  }
```

When I use postman to call the login API, it will straight away throttle the request after 1 success API call instead of after 3 requests. But after 60 seconds, I can call the login API once again, and the second time, will return status code 429 again.

So the question is why the throttle limit only 1 instead of 3?

Comment: Try setting this in main.ts, ```app.set('trust proxy', true)```

Comment: Got error `Property 'set' does not exist on type 'INestApplication'.`

Comment: Can you share your ```main.ts``` file here please.

Comment: main.ts   

``import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(helmet());
  app.enableCors();
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();``

Comment: ```const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(ApplicationModule);```. Add this instead of the line you used. ```app.set()``` can be used now.

Comment: Changed and `app.set()` is working. But the throttle still behave the same. Set limit to 3 requests but got 429 error code on the second API call

Comment: Keep trying any ideas, I'll see if i can find a solution in a local project. Good luck!